# using EntityFieldQuery to find a custom taxonomy field

Tags: database

I have the following query which works:

```
$query = "SELECT field_code_description_value FROM {field_data_field_code_description} WHERE bundle = :vocabulary AND entity_id in (SELECT entity_id FROM {taxonomy_term_data} WHERE name = :name)";
  $results = db_query($query, array(':name' => $fund_code, ':vocabulary'=>'fund_code'));
  $terms = $results->fetchObject();
```

I'm trying to convert this into using EntityFieldQuery, as it seems to be the best way to go (and I need some practice), but I couldn't get it right. This is what I tried:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
    $query
      ->entityCondition('entity_type','taxonomy_term')
      ->entityCondition('bundle','fund_code')
      ->fieldCondition('taxonomy_term_data','field_code_description', $fund_code, '=')
      //->propertyCondition('vid', $fundCodeTaxonomy->vid);

    $results = $query->execute();
    foreach($results['taxonomy_term'] as $tid) {
      $term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
      dpm($term);
    }
```

How do I properly use EntityFieldQuery here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `code_description` field does not appear in the `WHERE` condition of the original query. Therefore there is no need to add a `fieldCondition` on the `EntityFieldQuery` neither.

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query
  ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'taxonomy_term')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'fund_code')
  ->propertyCondition('name', $fund_code) ;

$results = $query->execute();
foreach($results['taxonomy_term'] as $tid) {
  $term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
  dpm($term);
  $items = field_get_items('taxonomy_term', $term, 'code_description');
  dpm($items);
}
```

However there is already the core function [taxonomy_get_term_by_name](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_term_by_name/7) doing exactly what you need here:

```
$terms = taxonomy_get_term_by_name($fund_code, 'fund_code');
foreach ($terms as $term) {
  dpm($term);
  $items = field_get_items('taxonomy_term', $term, 'code_description');
  dpm($items);
}
```